# Why Aren't The Second and Third Files Being Extracted From The Zip File?

Tags: vbscript

I am working on this VBScript that determines if a folder exist, if it does not it creates it. It then checks for the existence of a certain .zip file created by another program, and extracts the contents from it, and places it in 2 other locations.

Currently most of the functions work, but then when I get to the extraction part, I have a for each loop that goes through each item, and a series of if statements that compares then and at that point is supposed to extract each one to the desired location.

I have setup multiple breakpoints in my code, and through testing can see that it enters the For Each loop, and also completes the first if statement, and actually does extract the _lib file to it's proper location.

It then gets stuck in the space between the 2 if statements before finishing off the rest of the program. Can anyone tell me why it might not be reaching the second if statement? or what I can do to make this work as I have described?

Thanks.

```
 set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

set FilesInZip = objShell.NameSpace(FileZip).items



 For Each zedfile In FilesInzip


    If zedfile.name = "Fubar_Lib" Then

        If fso.FolderExists(FubarFolder&"Fubar_lib") Then

            fso.DeleteFolder(FubarFolder&"Fubar_lib")

        End If

        objShell.NameSpace(FubarFolder).CopyHere(zedfile)             

    End If

WScript.Echo "Exiting If1"



    If zedfile.name = "Fubar.jar" Then

        If fso.FileExists(FubarFolder&"Fubar.jar") Then

            fso.DeleteFile(FubarFolder&"Fubar.jar")

        End If

        objShell.NameSpace(FubarFolder).CopyHere(zedfile)            

    End If



    If zedfile.name = "RunFubar.cmd" Then

        If fso.FileExists(SecondFolder&"RunFubar.cmd") Then

            fso.DeleteFile(SecondFolder&"RunFubar.cmd")

        End If

        objShell.NameSpace(SecondFolder).CopyHere(zedfile)            

    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. By putting the extensions into the code I was preventing it from entering the second and third if statements.